# Slide back tableView row "Delete Row" option if user performs any activity other than delete operation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want the ability to have the option to delete certain rows of `UITableViewController`. The option is switched by a custom navigation bar dropdown menu [BTNavigationDropdownMenu](https://github.com/PhamBaTho/BTNavigationDropdownMenu) selected row using the standard tableView code below:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle { //let object = items[indexPath.row]
    if myPostStatus == true { return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete } else { return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
       // numbers.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, the problem is:
- When I have the dropdown row selected which gives the tableView ability to "delete. And I swipe the cell left (which shows the delete button) and for some reason directly touch the drop down menu to load the data which is not allow to be deleted, the app freezes with the following error.

`*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:1720`

If I manually slide back the cell to it's original position, and than tap the drop down menu to select new data (which can't be deleted) everything works fine without any issue and I can see the new data loaded in the tableView cell which does not gives the slide option to delete.

So, I think the problem is the slide open delete option. If there could be a way the active slide option to delete tableView cell would slide back when I touch the navigation bar menu, I am thinking that everything should work fine.

Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been coming back to you like second time I guess. The reason for crash may be because tableView.endUpdating() method is not being called after tableView.startUpdating. I am not going to get into other details regarding your custom navigation controller. But the easy way our for you is to just hide the navigation bar itself which contains your custom drop down item.

```
    override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

        navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

        self.tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

}
```

You can anyways get the navigation back. Read about customizing navigation bar to get more details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call tableView.endEditing before tapping anywhere else.

E.g. in `tableView(tableView willSelectRowAtIndex: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath?`

The exception probably comes from a changing NSIndexPath

Comment: In this case, how can I call something before tapping? Can you please guide?